# SQL Select 2 columns as list from single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I have a table with columns `[From], [To]`. I need to select these columns as a single list and I do it this way:

```
SELECT [From] FROM [TableX] WHERE (...)
UNION
SELECT [To] FROM [TableX] WHERE (...)
```

The problem is that I don't want to duplicate `WHERE (...)` condition as it's quite long. Is there a way to avoid this duplication?

Comment: if it is from the same table and `WHERE` absolutely the same why do you need to `UNION`?

Comment: Show us the WHERE clause, and it will be easier to understand the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a CTE to prevent duplicating your `WHERE` condition:

```
;WITH [CTE_Criteria] AS (
    SELECT [From], [To]
    FROM [TableX]
    WHERE (...)
)
SELECT [From] FROM [CTE_Criteria]
UNION
SELECT [To] FROM [CTE_Criteria];
```

Comment: I understood the problem to be the fact he had to include the same WHERE condition twice. In the query above it's only there once.

Comment: can you provide fidddle with this example please? with some simple `where`. I just never used this technique before.

Comment: @Alex SQLFiddle doesn't seem to be working, functional example here though: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/34f9f6378631fed5996cd5c5e1943be7

Answer (score 1):

Do the `UNION` in a derived table, and have one common `WHERE` clause.

```
select *
from
(
    SELECT [From] FROM [TableX] 
    UNION
    SELECT [To] FROM [TableX]
)
WHERE (...)
```

Comment: this will never work ;-) subquery contain just 1 column, but not all you have in table and in `WHERE` clause :-)

Comment: Depends on the WHERE clause... You can do two-level derived tables if its needed.

Comment: no it is not *depends*. Provide please any reasonable example when this query will bring same result as original one? `WHERE 1=1` ?

Comment: @Alex, I guess you're right, but since the question doesn't specify the where clause (and perhaps is a bit too simplified), I'll wait and see if OP edits the question.

Comment: but then *this is not an answer* ;-)

Comment: Call it whatever you want. A derived table can be convenient when doing UNION with similar where clauses.